# How to change Android emulator booting animation

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-framework, android-hardware, android-gui

How to change Android emulator booting animation

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a string.

Comment: I don't think you can change it, why would you anyway?

Comment: I think this question would *probably* be a better fit for either [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com), but I can't decide which.

Comment: Please don't tell me that is a client requirement.

Comment: That is almost certainly an image, and is most definitely baked into the firmware. If you want to change it, you'll have to create your own ROM.

Answer (score 4):

The emulator uses an Android OS image to boot. You can't change this without changing the image. This isn't emulator specific, but for Android in general.

For more information on how to do that, you might [look here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-change-customize-create-android-boot-animation-guide/), or just google "android change boot animation".

Once you have a new system image, run `emulator -help-disk-images` from your `sdk/tools` folder to see a ton of useful info about using disk images with your emulator. It tells you where to put the file, which differs depending on whether you're using the standard SDK or not.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a string, it is a bootanimation. You can't set it to another text. You can change it so it is another animation though.

If you want to see other possible boot animations, google android boot animations.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this is what most of my students and trainee ask about in every customization class.
The answer for that is - Of course you can modify that *image* . 
To make a long story short:
You can actually do it for every device by storing a noncompressed zip file at /data/local/bootanimation.zip  (just copy from CyanoGenMod and make sense of the animation layout and timing - that's the easiest way, and it explains much better than any explaination).

As I wrote in some other StackOverflow post, there are a couple of places you can do that (I disregard the encrypted case for the sake of simplicity):
system/media   and /data/local/ .
The latter is preferable as it makes it easier to modify, and does not require the tedious 
modification of the system.img (system partition) size.
Note that bootanimation.zip should be lowercase, and -0 compressed.

That is argueably the easiest Android customization (Well, if you have good graphic designers...)

Answer (score 0):

That's not part of your application, is emulating an device. Remember that each android device have it's own Start up images and icons that can be related to the carrier or the brand of the phone, etc.
You cannot change that image, anyhow for what propose you want to change that?

Comment: Yes you can. Changing boot animations is a common customization for rooted users. For the emulator, it's not much different.

Comment: but what's the purpose of that, when you are developing an app?...no one would see that change.

Comment: I don't think the OP expects users to see it, I think he just wants to change the emulator animation. True, it would probably be better on android.stackexchange.com, since it's not really a programming question. That's why I voted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Place a animation file in location /system/media/bootanimation.zip to override boot animation.
If you google around, you will find lot of tools to help you create boot animation (even from videos).